# How can I access to files through wifi

Tags: android, file, download, wifi, lan

I want to make an android Service that downloads files from local network through wifi to my android devices. The problem is that I dont know how can I access to the files. Can anyone help me how can I do that?

Comment: You need to provide more information than that. What protocol are you using to access the files? Http? FTP? SMB? What are you doing with the file once downloaded? Saving it? Viewing it?

Comment: @Badams I want to download it. Can't I just make an URL something like this: file://192.168.1.100/C:/path/file than download it like from the internet or I have to make a server?

Comment: Typically no. It depends how your computer with the IP 192.168.1.100 is setup. That might work if its setup as an SMB share.

Comment: @Badams file://192.168.1.100/C:/path/file I cannot just download it so easy. So I made a Windows shared folder and I want to somehow to access to it and save it to the phone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple search found this:

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Which seems to be what your looking for assuming your downloading over the HTTP protocol.

The problem with your question is the lack of information for someone to give you any sort of real help.

Comment: I want to transfer the files something like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer